# Замены бита в 8-битном числе

Tags: java

Нужно заменить один бит (с 0 на 1 и наоборот) на выбор в фиксированном 8-битном числе:

> 10011010

Выбирается число от 1 до 8. Например, при выборе 5 выводится 10010010 (5 бит изменился с 1 на 0)

К тому же нужно создать строку для вывода числа (int) в 8-битном формате:

```
String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(meinInteger)).replace(' ', '0');
```

Comment: А с чем возникли проблемы при решении задачи самостоятельно?

Comment: Не знаю даже, с чего начать.Задать число целиком или отдельно?

Comment: И в каком месте использовать эту строку для вывода чисел в 8ми битном формате

Comment: И еще вопрос, каким образом выбирать отдельный бит в числе? с помощью сканнера задавать число от 1 до 8?

Comment: _"целиком или отдельно"_ - что вы подразумеваете под этим? Откуда и в каком виде (просто байт, или int число 10011010, или строка "10011010") к вам приходит значение?

Comment: Задать каждый байт по отдельности а = 1, b = 0 и так далее или int = 10011010

Comment: 8 переменных - это слишком сурово. В виде int-а -да, можно, хоть по-честному надо задавать байтом. То есть число фиксированное, а не вводится откуда-то? Вводится только какой "бит" менять?

Comment: Да, число фиксированное, вводится только порядковый номер бита 1-8, который нужно поменять с 0 на 1 и наоборот
Я сама подумала, что 8 переменных слишком много, но из-за маленького опыта в программировании не знала, можно ли и с одной переменной реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Получаем позицию 1-8 (`place`). Откуда её брать и нужно ли её проверять на валидность значения - остаётся за рамками вопроса. В примере просто читается число из консоли
2. Записываем исходное число (`number`). Для удобства его можно задать [бинарным литералом](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html). Хранить ли его в виде `int` или `byte` - в данном случае не важно
3. Инвертируем (0 -> 1, 1 -> 0) нужный бит. Для этого можно воспользоваться [xor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)-ом с соответствующей степенью двойки. Степень двойки можно получить из единицы [побитовым сдвигом влево](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) на нужное количество позиций. Номера битов считаются справа налево, начиная с нуля, поэтому сдвиг делается не на `place` или `place - 1`, а на `8 - place`
4. Получаем результирующую строку с помощью указанной в вопросе конструкции

Пример итогового кода:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int place = scanner.nextInt();
int number = 0b10011010;
number ^= 1 << (8 - place);
String result = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(number)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(result);
```

При вводе 5 вывод:

> 10010010